# Update Time when user clicks buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Apparently I don't understand .val() very well.
I'm trying to have buttons where the user can click them and input the number of hours read. However I can't even get the basic buttons to work. Hopefully if I can get it working it won't be *too hard* to make the 4th click of the quarter hour button roll-over appropriately.
Here's my code, maybe you can tell me what dumb thing I'm doing:

HTML:

```
Time (H:MM): <span id="hoursread">0</span>:<span id="minutesread">00</span><br>
<button id="fifteen">+15 Minutes</button>
<button id="sixty">+1 Hour</button>
<button id="minus">-1 Hour</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#sixty').click(function () {
    $('#hoursread').val(+1);
});
$('#fifteen').click(function () {
    $('#minutesread').val(+15);
});
$('#minus').click(function () {
    $('#hoursread').val(-1);
});
```

I've been [fiddling](http://jsfiddle.net/aslum/CrL3c/5/) with this to no avail!

Comment: `.val()` is meant to be used with input elements. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CrL3c/6/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `text()` insead of `val()` for `span` having id `hoursread`, val() is used for input elements. Although you will have to calculate the time interval.